# Google Analytics showing partial data in magento

Tags: google-analytics, magento2, magento-2.3

Have just done a migration from 2.2.2 to 2.3.3.

Initially once migration was completed,  no data at all was recording in google analytics screen.

We the checked Analytics setting in the backend of the store:

***Stores>Configuration>Sales>Google API>Google Analytics***

It was disabled so we enabled it.

- Prior to migration, daily new users: 500.
- After migration, daily new users for the last 2 days: 140.
- Conversions: unaffected

Conclusion: analytics is not recording the data correctly.
Can anyone advise what else could be investigated why the data isn't accurate after 48hrs+?

and I can see also some google code in:

```
public_html/app/design/frontend/[vendor name]/[theme name]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml
```

````
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X');
</script>```
````

Answer (score 0):

The code is the standard one (it shouldn't be in the footer but in the header) and it track the pageviews, if it is in all pages you should have no user or session detection issues. Check if it is present on all pages. In addition, on the purchase confirmation page there must be the transaction code in addition to the one you entered here.

Comment: If it is in the footer, would that be a cause of inaccuracies of reporting?

Comment: The guidelines indicate to insert the code in the head so that it is executed first of all (or as soon as possible), placing it in the footer carries the risk that some other previous script creates a conflict.

Comment: Thanks Michele. 
I will see this is followed. I forgot to also mention something else. I have installed an extension for magento 2: Defer JS Parsing to improve page load. I have not excluded google analytics JS from this. Could this play a role?

Comment: It could be, plugins can give unexpected behavior. In this case you can only try.